# Cloud config server with external file and spring boot app

Tags: git, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I create a personal repository on Git where I have kept my properties file. 
I create a cloud config server ('my-config-server') and used the git repository url. 
I have bound my spring-boot application that is supposed to access the external properties file with Git repository.

Problem : Before using external properties file, my internal properties file was located at : src/main/resources and I was accessing it in my application using

```
@PropertySource("classpath:myproperties.properties)
```

But after using cloud config server , what all changes should i make in order to make my spring-boot application understand that now it has to fetch properties from the git repository?

I have added

```
services
   - my-config-server
```

in manifest.yml
I added  @EnableConfigServer and @RefreshScope

What else needs to be done? 
What to do about

```
 @PropertySource("classpath:myproperties.properties)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should replace the file `myproperties.properties` by a `bootstrap.yml` file that gives the url of your git repository :

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/config-repo
```

Then on the repository, you should rename `myproperties.properties` with `application.properties`. To access you properties, use the [`@Value`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html) annotation such as :

```
@Value("${my.color}")
private String myColor;
```

Read the [Spring Cloud Config reference](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-config/1.3.0.RELEASE/) for more details.

Comment: Thanks. 
Few Questions : 
1. In order to access the properties I use 'import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;' @Autowired public Environment env; env.getProperty("foo.bar"); because I dynamically need to pass a property and get it's value. Will your logic work with env.getProperty("") ?

Comment: 2.  in bootstrap.yml , the value of : 
spring:   cloud:    config:      server:        git:          uri: ssh://git@bitbucketjc-ssh.emp.net:7999/user/gaia.git
    work? It is a .git repository uri.
3. If I replace myproperties with application.properties then what should be the name of my external properties file ? application.properties or myproperties?

Comment: 1. Yes 2. Yes 3. `bootstrap.yml` will replace the file on the classpath and `application.properties` will be stored in the git repository.